# Vscode Extension Inline Completion toolbar menu disappeared

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VS Code extension and I am trying to develop a custom inline submenu. I am looking at an example on GitHub, and I have replaced the extension.ts file in the src folder with the following code:

source code : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/inline-completions

**extension.ts**

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { Range } from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log('inline-completions demo started');
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('demo-ext.command1', async (...args) => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('command1: ' + JSON.stringify(args));
    });

    const provider: vscode.InlineCompletionItemProvider = {
        async provideInlineCompletionItems(document, position, context, token) {
            console.log('provideInlineCompletionItems triggered');
            const regexp = /\/\/ \[(.+?),(.+?)\)(.*?):(.*)/;
            if (position.line <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            const result: vscode.InlineCompletionList = {
                items: [],
            };

            let offset = 1;
            while (offset > 0) {
                if (position.line - offset < 0) {
                    break;
                }

                const lineBefore = document.lineAt(position.line - offset).text;
                const matches = lineBefore.match(regexp);
                if (!matches) {
                    break;
                }
                offset++;

                const start = matches[1];
                const startInt = parseInt(start, 10);
                const end = matches[2];
                const endInt =
                    end === '*'
                        ? document.lineAt(position.line).text.length
                        : parseInt(end, 10);
                const flags = matches[3];
                const isSnippet = flags.includes('s');
                const text = matches[4].replace(/\\n/g, '\n');

                result.items.push({
                    insertText: isSnippet ? new vscode.SnippetString(text) : text,
                    range: new Range(position.line, startInt, position.line, endInt),
                });
            }
            return result;
        },
    };
    vscode.languages.registerInlineCompletionItemProvider({ pattern: '**' }, provider);
}
```

I have removed vscode.proposed.inlineCompletionsAdditions.d and I made changes to the source code to see if it can be configured only through package.json.
It was working fine until VS Code version 1.77.3, as shown in the image,
but starting from version 1.78.2, the "My Inline Completion Demo Settings" from package.json disappeared from the menu.
How can I resolve this issue?

**working screenshot**

[1.77.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6gN.png)

[1.78.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXu5.png)

I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you.

I would prefer if the addition could be made solely through the settings in the package.json file.